# Where const char* value will store. what is stack crash & heap crash?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack-overflow

1. If I define char array like below

   ```
   char arr[100] = "hello how are you";
   ```

   where is this string(`"hello how are you"`) stored exactly? (stack/heap/data area/somewhere else?).
2. Stack Overflow vs stack crash

   What is the difference between Stack Overflow and stack crash. When stack crash occurs?
3. Also heap overflow vs heap crash?
4. What happens when stack over flow/heap over flow occurs?

Comment: You have clearly separated your question into four distinct questions. These should be asked separately, clicking the ["Ask Question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button for each question. Please do this so we can answer each question separately :)

Comment: this might answer a part of ur question http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Answer (score 4):

1. String literals are stored in read-only memory and persist for the length of the program. Thus it is safe to return this pointer from a function

.

```
const char *f()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

In your case, you copy the contents of the string literal into a local char array variable. So the storage of `"hallo how are you"` and `char arr[100]` are different.

You can modify `arr` and each time your program flow gets back to that line, arr will be initialized with the original string literal again. You can't return a pointer to `arr` from a function, because `arr` is only a local variable.

Tip: only `char arr[] = "hallo how are you";` is necessary, unless you want to add more characters than are in your string literal.

2. I don't know what a "stack crash" is.
3. I'm not aware that heap can overflow. However, requests to allocate memory on the heap can fail. I don't know what a "heap crash" is.
4. When a stack overflow occurs, the program will typically crash. When a request to allocate heap memory fails, `malloc` will return NULL and `new` will throw `std::bad_alloc`

Comment: `char arr[100] = "hello how are you";` --> sounds better as initialization of the array.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Changed

Comment: `copy the contents of the string literal`  maybe this also needs re-wording.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why so? To what?

Comment: For clarity. To the same as above. initialization. `copy`ing usually reminds of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I wanted to be clear in plain English that the string literal is copied and not directly references by `arr`.